# When using the pseudo-class :target, how can I reverse the animation?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a dropdown menu, and when I click on an image, it scales and rotates.
This is all working well, but when I click on it again, I want it to return to it's normale state.

```
#arrow {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#arrow:target {
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg); 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: [Click me =)](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Cp5/)

Comment: So much fun spending time adding spaces in my code, but you'd be a bit more helpful if you could provide an answer...

Comment: Why not use javascript / jQuery?

Comment: Alot of people disable javascript. And  I've also fallen in love with html5 and css3.

Comment: `:target` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to "reverse" the application of `:target` that I'm aware of is to change the fragment in the link (or otherwise add a new `class` or something).

Aside from some `<input>` elements, there's no way to make state changes without a light application of JavaScript.

<kbd>[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Cp5/2/)</kbd>

**Edit**

[Here's an updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Cp5/4/) using a `<input type="checkbox">` with `:checked` instead of `:target` that does not involve JavaScript. YMMV depending on required browser support.

```
#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px; /* hide the checkbox off-screen */
    z-index: 2;
}

#arrow:before {
    width: 96px;
    height: 104px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 9999px; /* undo the checkbox offset */
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/s6m0zb4ev/arrow.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#arrow:checked:before {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg); 
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg);  
}
```

Comment: I know this works, and I could have done the same thing. But I am looking for a css subsitute. Still +1 for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

The `:target` selector is simply applying the styles to the image when the image is the target, which it is on click of the anchor as the images ID is the href of the anchor.

So by clicking the anchor again, it is still the same target so the styles will still be applied, it is not toggling them. This is the exact expected behaviour.

Can you not just use JS to toggle a class instead?

Comment: I'd like to exclude javascript as much as possible in styling a webpage.

Comment: It's not for _styling_ as such though, it's more functionality, if you get what I mean. It wouldn't take much js, so unless you're using absolutely none, then this won't do any harm. To be honest, it'd be better for cross browser support to not use a css animation and just go with js to do it all.

Comment: I am using absolutely none. And it's for specific browsers, I know they are compatible with css3 and html5.

Answer (score 1):

You can set another anchor under the arrow, and after the arrow has been clicked, swap z-index so that the next click goes to this one.

Then the active would be "noarrow", and not arrow.

```
body{
background-color: black;
}

.logo{
background:transparent url('http://s23.postimg.org/7xyndl53r/trans_bg.png') repeat center top;
height: 200px;
}

.arrow{
position: relative;
z-index:2;}

.text{
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: 1.6em !important;
margin-left: 3em;}



#arrow img {
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#arrow:target img, #arrow:focus img {
transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg); 
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(45deg); 
margin-top: 1em;
}

#arrow:target, #arrow:target div , #arrow:target img {
 z-index: -99;    
}


#text{
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
}

.noarrow {
    width: 200px;    
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Cp5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I used another anchor to close the div.
E.g. `<a href="#open">Open</a>` and `<a href="#close">Close</a>`
This will reverse the animation.

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/z6nya3c4/2/